# How can I get more detail infos on error message on mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

I run a find on mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
let User = require("@myRepo/myapp").user;

function getUser(){
   mongoose.set("debug", true);

   User.find({ _id: currentUserId })
      .limit(1)
      .exec(function(err, user) {
         if (err) {
            console.log("err: " + err);
            throw err;
         }

         console.log("user: ", user);
      });
 }
```

Find run successful but before exec run a mongoose error appear on console log every time. No err on function(err, user) is thrown!!!

It's a mongoose error:

```
myapp      | [2017-08-11T15:30:38.505Z] ERROR: sys/289 on 58e82c8426b7: Mongoose: user.find({ _id: 10646 }, { limit: 1, fields: {} }) (type=app)
```

There is no detail information on this mongoose error. How can I analyse this error?

mongoose.set("debug", true); - has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message:

```
myapp      | [2017-08-11T15:30:38.505Z] ERROR: sys/289 on 58e82c8426b7: Mongoose: user.find({ _id: 10646 }, { limit: 1, fields: {} }) (type=app)
```

is a typical mongoose log-message in mongoose debug mode. The text "ERROR:" in message is in my sense a bug.

If you comment or delete in code all

```
mongoose.set("debug", true);
```

and set [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) loglevel to "info" or lower

```
logging: {
  level: "info"
},
```

all log-messages (in our case all messages with "ERROR:") disappear.